# Cannot select column with accent in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the Level record in my rails app, it contains 1 field (name) that can contain chars with accents.

```
1.9.3p125 :008 > Level.all
 Level Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "levels".* FROM "levels" 
 => [#<Level id: 1, name: "Débutant">, #<Level id: 2, name: "Intermédiaire">, #<Level id: 3, name: "Avancé">]
```

But when I query, I have:

```
1.9.3p125 :011 > Level.where("name = ?", "D\U+FFC3\U+FFA9butant").first
 Level Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "levels".* FROM "levels" WHERE (name = 'Dbutant') LIMIT 1
 => nil
```

I cannot type `Level.where("name = ?", "Débutant").first` when using `rails c` as `é` is directly replaced by `\U+FFC3\U+FFA9`. But in my controller, the result is the same, I cannot query accentuated string.

I currently use sqlite for my tests.

Comment: Probably an encoding problem. Have you defined your application and your database as utf-8 ?

Comment: I think the DB should be fine as the Level.all returns the correct data, the Level.where only cannot filter when accents are present. Thanks, you'r right, I'll check the application.

Comment: config.encoding is correctly set to utf8 in application.rb. I've added  "encoding: utf8" in dabadase.yml but still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem in the console is related to the readline library: You have to install Ruby with proper readline support.

If you have installed Ruby using rvm, the quickest way to resolve this problem is:

```
rvm pkg install readline
```

and then (assuming you are using 1.9.3, otherwise just replace with your Ruby version):

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

After that, typing *é* in the Rails console should work again...

Regarding your other problem (in the controller): Could you please post a log excerpt containing the SQL query that is being made?

Comment: In development.log I have something like:  Level Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "levels".* FROM "levels" WHERE "levels"."name" = 'Débutant' LIMIT 1

Comment: So the query looks correct... Did you try to have a look at the data in the database directly? If you are using mysql you could use http://www.sequelpro.com/ on OSX or http://www.heidisql.com/ on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Place this string

```
#encoding: utf-8
```

to the first line of your Ruby file.